# How to read decimal value from parquet file using Morphline readAvroParquetFile and solar

Tags: hive, parquet, solar, morphline

Table with two columns(name string,salary decimal(10,3) and stored in parquet format in hive. While performing indexing using Morphline and solar getting the following exception:

```
ERROR morphline.MorphlineMapRunner: Unable to process file <parquet file>
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdio.AbstractParser.getAttachmentInputStream(AbstractParser.java:184)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdio.AbstractParser.doProcess(AbstractParser.java:94)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.ConvertTimestampBuilder$ConvertTimestamp.doProcess(ConvertTimestampBuilder.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.GenerateUUIDBuilder$GenerateUUID.doProcess(GenerateUUIDBuilder.java:98)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.avro.ExtractAvroPathsBuilder$ExtractAvroPaths.doProcess(ExtractAvroPathsBuilder.java:143)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.hadoop.parquet.avro.ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder$ReadAvroParquetFile.extract(ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder.java:201)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.hadoop.parquet.avro.ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder$ReadAvroParquetFile.doProcess(ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder.java:180)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.morphline.MorphlineMapRunner.map(MorphlineMapRunner.java:208)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.dryRun(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:1250)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.run(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:875)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.run(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.main(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:687)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Exception in thread "main" org.kitesdk.morphline.api.MorphlineRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.FaultTolerance.handleException(FaultTolerance.java:73)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.morphline.MorphlineMapRunner.map(MorphlineMapRunner.java:220)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.dryRun(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:1250)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.run(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:875)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.run(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.MapReduceIndexerTool.main(MapReduceIndexerTool.java:687)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdio.AbstractParser.getAttachmentInputStream(AbstractParser.java:184)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdio.AbstractParser.doProcess(AbstractParser.java:94)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.ConvertTimestampBuilder$ConvertTimestamp.doProcess(ConvertTimestampBuilder.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.stdlib.GenerateUUIDBuilder$GenerateUUID.doProcess(GenerateUUIDBuilder.java:98)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.avro.ExtractAvroPathsBuilder$ExtractAvroPaths.doProcess(ExtractAvroPathsBuilder.java:143)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.Connector.process(Connector.java:64)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.hadoop.parquet.avro.ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder$ReadAvroParquetFile.extract(ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder.java:201)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.hadoop.parquet.avro.ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder$ReadAvroParquetFile.doProcess(ReadAvroParquetFileBuilder.java:180)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.doProcess(AbstractCommand.java:186)
        at org.kitesdk.morphline.base.AbstractCommand.process(AbstractCommand.java:161)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.morphline.MorphlineMapRunner.map(MorphlineMapRunner.java:208)
        ... 11 more
```

following content from Morphline file:

```
{
  readAvroParquetFile {
   readerSchemaString:"""{"type":"record","name":"employee","fields":[
     {"name":"name","type":["string","null"],"default":""},
     {"name": "salary","type":

["bytes","null"],"logicalType":"decimal","precision":10,"scale":4,"default":0 }
   ]}"""
  }
}
```

Any help on how to index parquet file of a table contains decimal column using Morphline and solar.

Answer (score 0):

Per http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/morphlines/morphlines-reference-guide.html#readAvroParquetFile: "The morphline record input field file_upload_url must contain the HDFS Path of the Parquet file to read. (This field is already provided out of the box with MapReduceIndexerTool)."